# How to implement unit test for Azure Function TimerTrigger

Tags: java, azure-functions

Can somebody help how to write unit tests for below code using JUnit/Mockito?

```
    @FunctionName("nodeStats")
    public void nodeStats(@TimerTrigger(name = "nodeStatsTrigger", schedule = "0 */5 * * * *", dataType = "string") String timerInfo,
                          final ExecutionContext context) {
        getNodeStats();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The following docs might help:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-testing

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-add-output-binding-storage-queue-java#update-the-tests

A sample Test case gets automatically created for HTTP Triggered Function when you create a Java Function App:

```
    @Test
public void testHttpTriggerJava() throws Exception {
    // Setup
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    final HttpRequestMessage<Optional<String>> req = mock(HttpRequestMessage.class);

    final Map<String, String> queryParams = new HashMap<>();
    queryParams.put("name", "Azure");
    doReturn(queryParams).when(req).getQueryParameters();

    final Optional<String> queryBody = Optional.empty();
    doReturn(queryBody).when(req).getBody();

    doAnswer(new Answer<HttpResponseMessage.Builder>() {
        @Override
        public HttpResponseMessage.Builder answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
            HttpStatus status = (HttpStatus) invocation.getArguments()[0];
            return new HttpResponseMessageMock.HttpResponseMessageBuilderMock().status(status);
        }
    }).when(req).createResponseBuilder(any(HttpStatus.class));

    final ExecutionContext context = mock(ExecutionContext.class);
    doReturn(Logger.getGlobal()).when(context).getLogger();

    // Invoke
    final HttpResponseMessage ret = new Function().run(req, context);

    // Verify
    assertEquals(ret.getStatus(), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: Will it possible to add import statement for the class `HttpResponseMessageMock`?

Comment: Got it, we should own implementation for it. Found an example [here](https://github.com/gkgaurav31/file-share-function-test/blob/46d32c91e811c48dfd198887944fe3963e97bcbe/src/test/java/com/example/HttpResponseMessageMock.java#L1-L81)